# Firebase Query for uid of current user gives error that current user is null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

For my current react project I wanted to use the firebase storage and auth. The user is able to create basic objects with the shape

```
{
    createdAt: timestamp
    creator: uid of the user
    email: String
    name: String
}
```

Now I want to show the user all object that he has created. So I used

```
const auth = firebase.auth()
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const clientsRef = firestore.collection('clients');
const query = clientsRef.orderBy('createdAt').where('creator','==','auth.currentUser?.uid';

const Clients = () => {
const [clients] = useCollectionData(query);

return (
        <div className="client-list">
            <h1>Your Clients</h1>
            <div className="client-listing">
                {clients && clients.map(client => {
                    return <List>
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemText primary={client.name} />
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
)}
```

Since the user is logged in before this component is shown I thought that there should be a current user. However react keeps warning me that the current user is null and when I want to launch the code it shows me the error:

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

I tried to update the query on `auth.onAuthStateChanged`, however I ran into troubles as it wasn't able to run `useCollectionData` within the `onAuthStateChanged` as it gave me the error that the react hook has can't be called within a callback.

So how can I only show the data that is created by the user as showing all the data of course is not an option?

Comment: This line will give an error message, and will definitely not work: `clientsRef.orderBy('createdAt').where('creator','==','auth.currentUser.uid';` Are you sure this is what you use? If so, what error message do you get?

Comment: Sry I used `clientsRef.orderBy('createdAt`).where('creator','==','auth.currentUser?.uid');` The error then was `FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a hook for the user and check if the user is set. Then the query has to be updated.

```
const auth = firebase.auth()
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const clientsRef = firestore.collection('clients');
let query = clientsRef.orderBy('createdAt');

const Clients = () => {
    const [detailedClient, setDetailedClient] = useState({});
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [clients] = useCollectionData(query);
    const [user]  = useAuthState(auth);    
    if(user){
            query = clientsRef.where('creator','==',user.uid);
    }
```

This now updated the query as soon as the `authState` is changed due to the `useAuthState(auth)` hook. Then the query is updated with the `.where()`.