# FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined while doing Karma testing

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

As I was testing the application through `karma` and jasmine in the `angular cli`, there is this error that appears:

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data.
> Unsupported field value: undefined

What steps should I take to solve this problem? Is it within the `spec.ts` file of a component or is it already at the backend code of the project? Take note that this is my first time working with a project that uses `Firebase`

***`task-settings.component.ts`***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/services/task.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastService } from 'src/app/services/toast.service';
// modal dialog import
@Component({
  selector: 'task-settings',
  templateUrl: './task-settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-settings.component.css'],
})
export class TaskSettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  term!: string;
  dateToday = new Date();
  userData: any;
  fsData: any;
  id!: any;
  taskData: any;
  taskStatus: any = ['Pending', 'Completed'];
  taskScopeArray!: string[];
  newTaskScopeArray!: string[];
  addTaskForm!: any;
  newTaskForm!: any;
  taskRecipients: {
    uid: any;
    status: string;
    section: any;
    submissionLink: string;
    displayName: any;
  }[] = [];
  userPushTokens: { pushToken: string }[] = [];
  addTaskModal!: boolean;
  addScopeModal!: boolean;
  editTaskScope!: any;
  verifyTasks$: any;
  deleteTaskForm!: any;
  deleteTaskModal!: boolean;

  updateTaskForm!: any;
  updateTaskConfirm!: boolean;

  // editTaskScope! : any;
  // end of edit task import

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    readonly fire: AngularFireAuth,
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public toastService: ToastService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var d = new Date();
    var y = d.getFullYear();
    var n = d.getMonth();
    console.log(n);
    console.log(y);
    if (n >= 1 && n <= 6) {
      console.log('January to June');
      console.log('2nd Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1));
      this.term = '2nd Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1);
    } else if (n >= 8 && n <= 12) {
      console.log('August to December');
      console.log('1st Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1));
      this.term = '1st Term SY ' + y + '-' + (y + 1);
    } else {
      console.log('Summer Term' + y + '-' + (y + 1));
      this.term = 'Summer Term' + y + '-' + (y + 1);
    }
    this.updateTaskForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      deadline: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.fire.user.subscribe((user: any) => {
      this.userData = user;
      this.auth.getUserData(user?.uid).subscribe((res) => {
        this.fsData = res;
      });
    });
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: Params) => {
          console.log(params['id']);
          return this.taskService.getTask(params['id']);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.updateTaskForm.controls.title.setValue(res.title);
        this.updateTaskForm.controls.description.setValue(res.description);
        this.updateTaskForm.controls.deadline.setValue(res.deadline);
        this.taskData = res;
        console.log(res);
      });

    this.taskScopeArray = [];
  }

  public triggerDeleteTaskModal() {
    this.deleteTaskModal = !this.deleteTaskModal;
  }

  public triggerUpdateTask() {
    this.updateTaskForm.controls.title.setValue(this.taskData.title);
    this.updateTaskForm.controls.description.setValue(
      this.taskData.description
    );
    this.updateTaskForm.controls.deadline.setValue(this.taskData.deadline);
  }

  public updateTask() {
    if (this.updateTaskForm.valid) {
      this.taskService.updateTask(
        this.taskData.recipients,
        this.taskData.taskId,
        this.updateTaskForm.controls['title'].value,
        this.updateTaskForm.controls['description'].value,
        new Date (this.updateTaskForm.controls['deadline'].value),
      ).then(() => this.triggerUpdateTask())
      .finally(() => this.updateTaskForm.reset())
    }
    else if (this.updateTaskForm.invalid) {
      this.updateTaskForm.controls['title'].markAsTouched();
      this.updateTaskForm.controls['description'].markAsTouched();
      this.updateTaskForm.controls['deadline'].markAsTouched();


      this.toastService.publish("Please fillup all the requirements","formSuccess");

    }
  }

  changeTaskScope(e: any) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(typeof e.target.value);
  }

  public deleteTask() {
    this.taskService.deleteTask(this.taskData.taskId).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    });
  }
}
```

***`task-settings.component.spec.ts`***

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/services/task.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastService } from 'src/app/services/toast.service';
import { TaskSettingsComponent } from './task-settings.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('TaskSettingsComponent', () => {
  let component: TaskSettingsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TaskSettingsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TaskSettingsComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), AngularFireDatabaseModule, HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule ],
      providers: [ AuthService, TaskService, ToastService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TaskSettingsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

***`app.module.ts`***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../app/dashboard-components/dashboard/dashboard.component'
import { LoginComponent } from './auth-components/login/login.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './auth-components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { MyProfileComponent } from './my-profile-components/my-profile/my-profile.component';
import { UserManagementComponent } from './user-management-components/user-management/user-management.component';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination'; // <-- import the module
import { AngularFireFunctionsModule } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserComponent } from './user-management-components/user/user.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './dashboard-components/task/task.component';
import { TaskSettingsComponent } from './dashboard-components/task-settings/task-settings.component';
import { ReportComponent } from './dashboard-components/report/report.component';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { VerifyTaskComponent } from './user-management-components/verify-task/verify-task.component';

import { UserManualComponent } from './user-manual/user-manual.component';
import { ArchiveComponent } from './archive/archive.component';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PagenotfoundComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MyProfileComponent,
    UserManagementComponent,
    UserComponent,
    TaskComponent,
    TaskSettingsComponent,
    ReportComponent,
    VerifyTaskComponent,
    UserManualComponent,
    ArchiveComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ChartModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule, //Firebase imports
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***`task.service.ts`***

```
public setRecipients(scope:string):Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users',ref => ref.where('section','==',scope))
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((doc: any) => {
        // console.log(doc)
        return doc.map(
          (c: { payload: { doc: { data: () => any; id: any; }; }; }) => {
            const data = c.payload.doc.data();
            const id = c.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          }
        )})
    );
  }

  public getTask(id:string):Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('tasks',ref => ref.where('taskId','==',id))
    .doc(id)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((doc: any) => {
        // console.log(doc)
        return { id: doc.payload.id, ...doc.payload.data() };
      })
    );
  }
  public getCompletedTask(): Observable<any> {
    return this.afs
      .collection('tasks', (ref) =>
        ref.where('status', '==', 'Completed').orderBy('createdAt')
      )
      .snapshotChanges()  
      .pipe(
        map((doc: any) => {
          // console.log(doc)
          return doc.map(
            (c: { payload: { doc: { data: () => any; id: any } } }) => {
              const data = c.payload.doc.data();
              const id = c.payload.doc.id;
              return { id, ...data };
            }
          );
        })
      );
  }
```

***`user.service.ts`***

```
public getDeptHeadUsers():Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('role','==','Department Head').orderBy('createdAt','desc'))
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((doc: any) => {
        // console.log(doc)
        return doc.map(
          (c: { payload: { doc: { data: () => any; id: any; }; }; }) => {
            const data = c.payload.doc.data();
            const id = c.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          }
        )})
    );
  }
  public getStudentUsers():Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('role','==','Student',).orderBy('createdAt','desc'))
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((doc: any) => {
        // console.log(doc)
        return doc.map(
          (c: { payload: { doc: { data: () => any; id: any; }; }; }) => {
            const data = c.payload.doc.data();
            const id = c.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          }
        )})
    );
  }
  public getAdminUsers():Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('role','==','CICS Office Staff').orderBy('createdAt','desc'))
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((doc: any) => {
        // console.log(doc)
        return doc.map(
          (c: { payload: { doc: { data: () => any; id: any; }; }; }) => {
            const data = c.payload.doc.data();
            const id = c.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          }
        )})
    );
  }
```

***`auth.service.ts`***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth  } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastService } from './toast.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private fns: AngularFireFunctions,
    readonly fire: AngularFireAuth, 
    public router: Router,
    public toastService: ToastService
  ) {
    this.fire.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.getUserData(user.uid).subscribe(res => {
          if (res.role != 'CICS Office Staff' && res.role != 'Department Head') {
            this.signOut().then(() => {
              this.toastService.publish('You are not allowed to access the web system. Please use the mobile application.','userDoesNotExist');
            })
          } else if (res.role == 'CICS Office Staff' || res.role == 'Department Head') {
              console.log('Authenticated')
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.log('logged out');
      }
    })
  }

  public signup(email:string, password:string,displayName:string,contactNumber:string) {
    return this.fire.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      // Update the user info with the given name
      .then(res=> {
        res.user?.updateProfile({displayName: displayName})
        .then(() => {
          const data = {
            uid: res.user?.uid,
            contactNumber: contactNumber,
            email: email,
            displayName: displayName,
            createdAt: Date.now(),
            role: 'CICS Office Staff'
          }
          this.afs.collection('users')
          .doc(res.user?.uid).set(data)
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
        })
        .then(() => {res.user,console.log(res.user)})
      })
  }

  public signOut(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Signing-out');
    //this.guard.prompt('signIn').then(user => {})
    return this.fire.signOut()
    .then(() => {this.router.navigate(['/login'])})
  }

  public signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.fire.setPersistence('local').then(()=> {
      this.fire.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(a => console.log('logged in!'))
      .then(a => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']))
      .catch((err) => {
        this.toastService.publish('The credentials you have entered does not match any user in our database','userDoesNotExist');
      })
    })
  }

  public getUserData(id:string):Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users')
    .doc(id)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map((doc: any) => {
        // console.log(doc)
        return { id: doc.payload.id, ...doc.payload.data() };
      })
    );
  }

  public sendPasswordReset(email: string) {
    return this.fire.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(res => { console.log(res), this.toastService.publish('Email has been sent to ' + email,'formSuccess')}).catch((err) => {
      this.toastService.publish('The credentials you have entered does not match any user in our database','userDoesNotExist');})
  }
//firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string,contactNumber:string

  public changeEmail(currentEmail:string, newEmail:string, password:string,id:string): Promise<any> {
    return this.fire.signInWithEmailAndPassword(currentEmail,password).then((res) => {
      res.user?.updateEmail(newEmail).then(() => {
        this.afs.collection('users').doc(id).set({
          email: newEmail
        }, { merge: true }) })
        .catch(() => {
          this.toastService.publish('The email ' + newEmail + ' is already registered in our database!','userDoesNotExist')
        })
    })
    .then(() => this.toastService.publish('Your email has been updated to ' + newEmail,'formSuccess'))
    .catch(() => this.toastService.publish('The credentials you have entered does not match any user in our database','userDoesNotExist'))
  }

 public editMyProfile(displayName:string, contactNumber:string, currentEmail:string, password:string,id:string): Promise<any> {
    return this.fire.signInWithEmailAndPassword(currentEmail,password).then((res) => {
      res.user?.updateProfile({displayName: displayName})
    }).then(() => {
      this.afs.collection('users').doc(id).set({
        contactNumber: contactNumber,
        displayName: displayName,
      }, { merge: true })
    })
    .then(() => this.toastService.publish('Your profile has been updated','formSuccess'))
    .catch(() => this.toastService.publish('The password you have entered is incorrect','userDoesNotExist'))
  }
  public deleteMyProfile(email:string,password:string,id:string): Promise<any> {
    return this.fire.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then((res) => {
      this.afs.collection('users').doc(res.user?.uid).delete()
      .then(() => {
        res.user?.delete()
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.toastService.publish('Your account with the credentials ' + email + " has been deleted from our system",'userDoesNotExist')      
      })
    }).catch(() => {
      this.toastService.publish('The credentials you have entered does not match any user in our database','userDoesNotExist');
    })
  }

  public changeMyPassword(email:string, oldPassword:string, newPassword:string): Promise<any> {
    return this.fire.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,oldPassword).then((res) => {
      res.user?.updatePassword(newPassword)
      .then(() => {
        this.toastService.publish('Your password has been updated','formSuccess')
      })
    }).catch(() => {
      this.toastService.publish('The credentials you have entered does not match any user in our database','userDoesNotExist');
    })
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is often caused by your query receiving a `null` or `undefined` argument value, which can come from your application not [checking for null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433942/) before executing queries, or that the application does not wait for [authentication to be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879183/) before querying Firestore. Looking at your code, I would check the `AuthService` and `TaskService` modules, since those seem to handle querying and authenticating.

The documentation provides a [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) that explains how to listen for authentication state changes before proceeding or setting values which will be used for querying:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Otherwise, you could share the modules which handle querying to see in detail how the queries are executed, and how authentication is happening.

Comment: hello there, I added already the modules that are handling querying

Comment: After looking at your `task` and `auth` service modules, the recommendation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68435640/16929894) would likely prevent this error from showing up, since your queries are receiving undefined data. As to why the data is `undefined` in the first place it does not seem clear. The AngularFire [repository](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/test/ng-build/ng9) does include a sample test app, in addition to this other testing [repository](https://github.com/SpiralOutDotEu/AngularFire-Auth-app) which can help set up the test environment.

Comment: but the problem is, the `auth` service doesn't really have a `.where()` function in it, only in the `task` and `user` service modules, how can I apply the changes those service modules?